# Why don't ant bites kill us?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, biochemistry

So, methanol is supposed to be toxic even in minute quantities because it is oxidised in our body to methanal and then methanoic acid. This can cause blindness and even death.
Interestingly, ants eject the very same methanoic acid inside us when they bite us, and I haven't heard anyone die of that.
Is it because of the minuteness of the quantity in which it is secrete, or is there some other explanation to this?

Comment: Typical supposed lethal dose of methanol for humans is 20-30 mL. Formic acid is not dramatically more toxic than acetic acid. See LD50 here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formic_acid

Comment: Famously, the dose makes the poison.

Comment: Because we never met ["them"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Them!).

Comment: Of course, being staked out atop an anthill might have adverse health effects...

Comment: Fire ants: https://abcnews.go.com/GMA/Health/story?id=2143091&page=1